# How to refresh p:graphicImage which gets image from servlet?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have multiple `<p:graphicImage>`s which gets the image from a servlet by ID. I need to refresh the image when the user has removed or changed the image, so that it disappears or changes instead of showing the old one.

How can I achieve this? Could I use JavaScript or jQuery for this?

Comment: If the event-based model is a requirement, then you have quite a bit of work on your hands. otherwise, use either of primefaces [poll](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/poll.jsf) or [push](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/index.jsf)